# interfacing with D Properly return an Array of Struct

Tags: c#, pointers, interop, d

this question is referring to the 'new' D :
**DMD32 D Compiler v2.068.2**

> for TL;DR if you don't need details skip to the question below

working with visual studio(i am using v2010), by creating a `new project` ->  `D` -> `Dynamic Library`

when the project creartion process is complete, in the solution explorer
there's 2 files:

- dllmain.d
- dll.def

leaving the `.def` file as it is, i have managed to understand that 
by adding some new functions to the `dllmain.d` and prefexing with :

```
extern (Windows) export
```

will export the the function and it will be callable from `c#`, didn't try it with `C` or `C++`.

<sub>side note, do not touch any of the existing code unless you know what you're doing.</sub>

so the code below works as expected

```
extern (Windows) export uint D_mathPower(uint p)
{     
    return p * p; 
}
```

calling it from C# with the following signature:

```c#
    [DllImport(@"pathTo...\DynamicLib1.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    public static extern uint D_mathPower(uint p);
```

I could easy use it as follows:

```
uint powD = D_mathPower(5);
```

## **my question  is**

how do i return an array of structs (preferably the most cost-efficient way) ?

```
struct dpack{ char* Name; uint Id; }
```

i have tried using both `char[]` and `char*` but with no success.

this is my code so far

```
extern (Windows) export
dpack[] D_getPacks(uint size)
{
    dpack[] rtDpArr = new dpack[size];
    char[] str = "someText".dup;

    for(uint i=0; i<size; i++)
    {

        str[$ - 1] = cast(char)('0' + i % (126 - '0'));
        rtDpArr[i].Id = i;
        rtDpArr[i].Name= str.dup;
    }
   return rtDpArr;
}


void getPacksPtr(uint size, dpack** DpArr)
{
 // this is the signature i have successfully implemented via c++
}
```

Comment: returning D arrays to another language can work but usually doesn't because the ABI details won't necessarily match. Try making your own struct type with pointer and length for the interop or do something like `getArray(size_t* lengthPtr, dpack** ptrPtr) { *lengthPtr = array.length; *ptrPtr = array.ptr; }`

Comment: You should practice creating a C DLL and using it in C# before trying it with a D DLL. Figure out how to use C functions that return "arrays" from C#, then use the same technique in D. C# doesn't have any knowledge of how D stores slices, so you won't be able to use them as-is.

Answer (score 1):

Because a D array has a special layout you should rather return a pointer to the first item. Then in C# you can cast each item from the base pointer by reading 8 bytes per 8 bytes (this matches `dpack.sizeof`), since you already know the count:

```
struct dpack{ immutable(char)* Name; uint Id; }

extern (Windows) export
void* D_getPacks(uint count)
{
    dpack[] rtDpArr = new dpack[count];
    char[] str = "someText".dup;

    import std.string;
    for(uint i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        rtDpArr[i].Id = i;
        // add a trailing '\0'
        rtDpArr[i].Name = toStringz(str);
    }
    // pointer to the first item
    return rtDpArr.ptr;
}
```

Also to cast the `.Name` member it's necessary to add a terminator, otherwise you cant know the length of the string. This is done by `std.string.toStringz` which will add a null character at the end of the string. The `char* Name` member can then be cast as are usually strings provided by a function in a dll with a C interface.

Comment: hey thanks @Nested type ..for the code, i have tested so many variations but none included `std.string` i have tried your code after i allready found an answer and after benchmarking against `c++` implementation, i then tested with `std.string` and the performance was droped to 0.75% compared to `char*` field. and as to the fastest code in D (so far) which is what i have posted.. it's still slower than the fastest aproach in c++ is also 0.75% of the `c++`  code so c++ was 45 ms, `D (char*)` was 57 ms, and `D (std.string)` was 79 ms.

Comment: what is strange is that every time i call the function the content is different the tail at element[0] could once be `G` then executing it again it's `;` then it's 'G' again not stable, does it have anything to do with `malloc` without `free` or what could it be ?

Answer (score 0):

this is the most efficient way i could implement it .

```
extern (Windows) export
void D_getPacksPtr(uint size, dpack** DpArr)
{
    *DpArr = cast(dpack*) malloc(size * dpack.sizeof);
    dpack* curP = *DpArr;
    char[] str = "abcdefghij".dup;
    uint i=0;
    while(i!=size){
        str[$ - 1] = cast(char)('0' + i % (126 - '0'));
        curP.Name = cast(char*)str.dup; curP.Id = i;
        ++i;++curP;
    }
}

    [DllImport(@"PathTo...\DynamicLib1.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    public static extern void D_getPacksPtr(uint size, dpack** DPArr);
```

using it :

```
    dpack* outDpack;
    D_getPacksPtr(500000, &outDpack);
```